# Swedish Characters in Address bar and .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

In my search the use of `ä,å and ö` characters are needed to be used. However if the URL is:

```
www.example.com?search.phpcity=Strängnäss
```

It will display this in the address bar:

```
www.example.com?search.php?city=Str%E4ngn%E4ss
```

I also would love to know how to eliminate the `.php` the `?` and `=` so my link would look like this:

```
www.example.com/search/city/Strängnäss
```

Any links or information on how to achieve this will be great and much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA,NC,B,NE]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)